# Swift first row with a uitable has a uicollectionview that has a different height from the rest of the other rows in the uitable

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm relatively new to swift and iOS. How can I implement than app that looks like the updated instagram. : the first row has a collection of height x, but the rest of the cell have image views of height `x+y`. Checkout what I mean in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAdM6.jpg), my rep is too low to upload an image. Lol :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Different cell size in UICollectionview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16061804/different-cell-size-in-uicollectionview)

Answer (score 1):

Implement the UITableView's delegate method `func tableView(UITableView, heightForRowAt: IndexPath)`
Then you can return any height for each `indexPath`.  The easiest option would be to make that its own section, and then the rest of the same sized rows another section.

Answer (score 0):

if your cells' height are different, you should in the methord `func tableView(UITableView, heightForRowAt: IndexPath)` make sure the height of cell according to the modal for the cell.